# Add image from Google Drive in Google Sheet and convert it into CSV

Tags: google-sheets

Is that possible to add an image from the Drive to Google Sheet and when we download in CSV format we need image URL, currently it is not showing any URL when I tried to download in CSV format?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.

Among many possible alternatives, here is one: before downloading the spreadsheet as CSV, add the image's URL as viewable cell value

Notes:

1. Don't use [IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en) function as the image URL is not displayed.
2. You could use [HYPERLINK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en) with only the first argument, the image URL.

Besides the above, you could send a feature request to Google through Google Feedback. Open the spreadsheet, then click on Help > Report a problem

Comment: is it possible with script function "on select image add image and image public url"

Comment: @Midhilaj Follow up questions should be posted as new questions.